# If $T$ proves any incorrect $\forall$-rudimentary sentence, then $T$ is inconsistent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness, formal-systems

> A theory $T$ in the language of arithmetic is called
>   $\omega$-inconsistent if for some formula $F(x)$, $\exists x F(x)$ is
>   a theorem of $T$, but so is $\neg F(n)$ for each natural number $n$.
>   Let $T$ be a theory in the language of arithmetic extending $Q$.
>
> Show that:
>
> If $T$ proves any incorrect $\forall$-rudimentary sentence, then $T$
>   is inconsistent
>
> If $T$ proves any incorrect $\exists$-rudimentary sentence, then $T$
>   is $\omega$-inconsistent.

It seems like I'm having a lot of trouble with terminology here. If someone could clarify some things for me I would be very appreciative. First of all, what does it mean for $\exists x F(x)$ to be a "theorem" of $T$? Does this just mean that $\exists x F(x)$ is a sentence/equation within the set $T$? Are there practical examples that will help me see what we mean by $\omega$-inconsistency in the context of this problem ("...then so is $\neg F(n)$ for each natural number n")? Also, if $\neg F(n)$ holds for each natural number $n$, then how can we have $\exists x F(x)$? Does this just imply that $x$ is not a natural number?

Additionally, what does it mean to prove some "incorrect" $\forall$/$\exists$-rudimentary sentence (as opposed to proving a "correct" one)?

Comment: Do you know about *first-order logic* (and **not** *propositional logic*) ? A formal system is made of *language* (symbols, expressions, formulae), *axioms* (like : $x + 0 = x$), *rules of inferences* (like *modus ponens*). A *theorem* is a formula *derivable* from axioms through rules of inference. Which is your textbook ? Do you know what is an "$∀$-rudimentary sentence" ?

Comment: For the reference, see George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, *Computability and Logic* (5th ed - 2007), Problem 16.3 page 217.

Comment: The definition of *$\omega$-inconsistent* is in the statement of the problem [page 217]. The definition of *rudimentary formula* is at page 204. For *non-standard* interpretations ("does this just imply that $x$ is not a natural number?") see bottom page 210.

Comment: $Q$ is the *minimal arithmetic*; see page 208 for its axioms : "The theory $Q$ of *minimal arithmetic* is the set of all sentences of the language of arithmetic that are provable from (or, equivalently, are true in all models of) these axioms."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is it possible for you to perhaps show the proof of the first problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start from the definition of $\forall$-rudimentary :

> By a *rudimentary formula* of the language of arithmetic we mean a formula built
>   up from atomic formulas using only negation, conjunction, disjunction, and bounded
>   quantifications $∀x < t$ and $∃x < t$, where $t$ may be any term of the language (not involving $x$). (Conditionals and biconditionals are allowed, too, since these officially
>   are just abbreviations for certain constructions involving negation, conjunction, and
>   disjunction. [...] ). By an *$∃$-rudimentary formula* we mean a formula of form $∃xF$ where $F$ is rudimentary, and similarly for an *$∀$-rudimentary formula*.

In the system $Q$ of *minimal arithmetic*, the atomic formulas are basically of the form :

$x = 0$, $x < 1$, and so on.

Thus an example of $\forall$-rudimentary *sentence* [i.e.closed formula] that is *incorrect* can be :

> $\forall x(x = 1)$.

It is clearly *incorrect* [i.e.not *true* in the standard interpretation] because we know that not *all* numbers are equal to $1$.

Assume that :

$T \vdash \forall x(x = 1)$

i.e. that $T$ (which extend $Q$) proves the incorrect ∀-rudimentary sentence above.

By the rules of f-o logic, we can derive in $T$ all *instances* of it, like : $0 = 1$.

But see (page 208) the proof of **Theorem 16.13** :

> All of $0 \ne 1, 0 \ne 2, 0 \ne 3$, . . . , are provable [in $Q$, and thus in $T$].

In conclusion, we have that $T$ proves $0 = 1$ and also $\lnot 0 = 1$, and this is a *contradiction*; thus $T$ will be *inconsistent*.

You have to argument in this way also for the second part of your problem; consider an $\exists$-rudimentary sentence like :

> $\exists x(x < 0)$.

It is clearly *incorrect*. Now, exploiting the fact [see page 208] :

> that $\lnot 1 < 1, \lnot 2 < 1$, . . . are provable [in $Q$]

we conlcude that $∃xF(x)$ is a theorem of $T$, but so is $\lnot F(n)$ for each natural number $n$, i.e. $T$ is $\omega$-inconsistent.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: @user1038665 - but you have to check the details; the problem asks for : "If $T$ proves **any** incorrect ..." and I have consider only one example of ...

Comment: How can we generalize this? I suspect we can say that if $T$ proves some incorrect $\forall$-rudimentary sentence $L$, then the corresponding sentence/axiom $R$ that contradicts $L$ is correct in $Q$ and thus also correct in $T$ (i.e. $Q \vdash R$, so $T \vdash R$). So, $T$ is trivially inconsistent because $(T \vdash R) \wedge (T \vdash \neg R)$ where $\neg R \equiv L$.

Comment: However, is there any formal way we can say that there will always be a corresponding sentence that contradicts $L$? Also, for the second question, can you help me understand the $\omega$-inconsistency more clearly?

Comment: @user1038665 - I think so; consider the proof of **Th 16.13**: it check all cases in order to conclude that [page 210] $Q$ proves "any correct rudimentary sentence". Thus, we have to "convince ourselves" that from the proof (in $T$) of an *incorrect* $\forall$-rudimentary, we can derive (by instantiation) a proof of an *incorrect* rudimentary. But an incorrect rudimentary is the *negation* of a *correct* rudimentary; thus, due to the fact that $Q$ proves all correct ones, we have the contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

The key point is that $Q$ (and therefore $T$) proves every correct $\Sigma^0_1$ (i.e. $\Sigma$-rudimentary) sentence in the language of arithmetic. Here a "correct" sentence is one that holds in the standard model of arithmetic.

The problem follows from the key point almost immediately using simpler facts about negations of formulas and the definitions of consistency and $\omega$-consistency.